# Strange clause in Javascript the Good Parts

Tags: javascript, clause

This code is from the section of [recursion](http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/programming/javascript/9780596517748/functions/recursion).

```
var getElementsByAttribute = function (att, value) {
    var results = [];

    walk_the_DOM(document.body, function (node) {
        var actual = node.nodeType === 1 && node.getAttribute(att);
        if (typeof actual === 'string' &&
                (actual === value || typeof value !== 'string')) {
            results.push(node);
        }
    });

    return results;
};
```

I don't understand the point of the clause below:

```
typeof actual === 'string' && (actual === value || typeof value !== 'string')
```

How is it different from?

```
typeof actual === 'string' && actual === value
```

Comment: the first condition is true for `value === 42`

Comment: Ohhhh, after staring at this for like 5 minutes I finally realized that the `string`ness of two _different_ variables are being tested `value` and `actual`.

Comment: @AlexWayne I should have stared longer...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
typeof actual === 'string' && (actual === value || typeof value !== 'string')
```

This will return `true` if and only if `actual` is a string, and either `actual === value`, or `value` is not a string.

```
typeof actual === 'string' && actual === value
```

This will return `true` if and only if `actual` is a string and either `actual === value`.

In other words, the first condition returns true if `value` is anything other than a string, whereas the second condition will only return true if it is a string, and strictly equal to `actual`.